# Items ordered edit not working but it was working before

Tags: magento2, orders, error, edit

[image]

Edit button is not working here... I dont know from where to start checking why its not working, any sugessions?

update: Edit button returns an error 
error: "Could not receive Stock Item data"

another update
after debugging thinking that the problem is somewhere here

```
   getLoadFromData:function(){
            var orderId = this.getCurrentOrderId();
            return {'form_key':FORM_KEY, 'order_id':orderId};
        },
```

Comment: IWD OrderManager is the module

Comment: License is active thats not the problem